# Using a double pointer, how do you fill a 2D with Strings?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am reading a text file line by line. Putting each line into a 2d array. Sometimes the program works, but usually the first element of the 2d array returns as gibberish, example: `W@??.

I've looked at the other examples on StackOverflow and can't see where this code is going wrong.

```
int read_file(FILE* file, char ** strings) {
  char str[100];
  int n = 0;
  while(fgets(str, 100, file)) {
      if(n > 0) {
        strings = realloc(strings, (n+1) * sizeof(char)); 
      }
      int len = strlen(str);

      if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') {
        str[len-1] = '\0';
      }
      len = strlen(str) +1;
      strings[n] = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(strings[n], str);
      puts(strings[n]);         //THIS PRINTS THE CORRECT OUTPUT
      n++;
  }

  puts(strings[0]);      //THIS PRINTS GIBBERISH, `W@??
  puts(strings[1]);
  puts(strings[2]);

return n;
}

    
int main(void) {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("data.txt", "r");

  char ** strings = malloc(sizeof(char*));

  int n = read_file(file, strings);
  fclose(file);
  
  //print_strings(strings, n);


  puts(strings[0]);      //THIS PRINTS GIBBERISH, `W@??
  puts(strings[1]);
  puts(strings[2]);


  //freeAllocatedMemory(strings, n);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: `double *x` is a "double pointer".  `char **x` is a "pointer to pointer"

Comment: @user3121023 : sizeof(char*) makes sense, thank you. Why does char** need to be returned though? Doesn't changing a pointer mean the changes are visible wherever is is accessed?

Comment: Makes sense. thanks again

Comment: Using `char**` here is a mistake. You should probably use either a dynamically extended array, or some kind of linked-list structure to store data as you read it.